# What are the ethical implications of creating (possibly sentient) AI systems?

Tags: ethics

As I have been looking at other questions on this site (like [this](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/60/what-are-the-main-problems-hindering-current-ai-development), [this](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/1376/is-it-ethical-to-implement-self-defence-for-street-walking-ai-robots), [this](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/111/how-would-self-driving-cars-make-ethical-decisions-about-who-to-kill), and [this](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/1289/can-we-destroy-artificial-general-intelligence-without-its-consent)), I have been thinking more about the ethical implications of creating these generalized AI systems. It seems that whether or not we *can* create it is not rationale enough as to whether or not we *should* do it.

In dealing with the issue of ethics in AI, I wonder what the ethical implications are not just for us, but for the system itself. It seems to extend beyond the usually asked questions on the topic and into unknown territory. Are ethics computable? Can they be implemented programmatically? Can we force an AI system to do something against its *"will"*?

What does the creation of AI imply ethically for us as well as the AI?

Answer (score 1):

I believe if an AI achieves sentience, it should be treated the same way we are required to treat any other sentient animal. This is belief though, there is no established ethics for AI. But there were no ethics for animals a couple of centuries ago.

Comment: Why the downvote? Is there any established ethics for AI? Or you think AI shouldn't have rights?